# select a column based on multiple condition (many to many relation)

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, many-to-many

Okay, well I know title might be a little unclear, but I couldn't find a better title. Let me explain the situation,

I have 3 tables (actually many, but for this example we need 3).
1. `teachers` table with columns `teacherid, teachername, other columns (DOB etc)...`
2. `classes` table with columns `classid, classname, other columns (students in class etc)`
3. `subjects` table with struct `subjectid, subjectname, other columns (unimportant at this point)`

now as you can probabably guess from tables, that there exists a many to many relationship, as one teacher can teach many classes, also, one teacher can teach many subjects, and one class can have many subjects etc etc. So the tables that contain these many to many relationship are..
4. `ClassSubject` columns `ClassId, SubjectId, CustomRemark`
5. `TeacherSubject` columns `TeacherId, SubjectId, CustomRemark`
6. `TeacherClass` columns `TeacherId, ClassId, CustomRemark`

Again you might guess, table 4 represents a map of what class have what subjects (first two col are marked primary key). table 5 represents what teacher can teach what subject(s) (first two col marked as pk), again table 6 represent what teacher can teach what classes. (I just hope I am explicit enough to not to confuse you!)

Now the problem is, at one point I have this dictionary, `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, List<int>>> dctClsSubTeachers` that stores in the given order, id of the class, for each id of class, another dictionary that contains id of subject, and for that id of the class, and that if of subject a list of teacher that can teach that subject in the corresponding class. (it might sound a little complex, but please think over it for a minute I am sure it will make sense :(

**So, I need to populate this dictionary, thus I need a query thought which I can supply classId and subjectId as parameters, and I get a list of all the teacher that can not only just teach that subject, but teach that subject in the class given in parameter, (we have table 4, 5 and 6 for relationship), thus I could populate that dictionary**

Just so you know, I've tried a lots of ways, but none of them worked, a couple that I tried are..

```
select teacherId from teachers where teacherid in (SELECT teacherid from teacherclass where classid = k
intersect
SELECT teacherid from teachersubject where subjectid = k2) // I can't use this because access doesn't support intersect
```

another one I tried

```
SELECT teacherid
FROM Teachers, (ClassSubject INNER JOIN TeacherClass ON ClassSubject.ClassId = TeacherClass.ClassId) INNER JOIN TeacherSubject ON ClassSubject.SubjectId = TeacherSubject.SubjectId;
```

and I have tried a couple of more, but couldn't do it, after 10hr of headache, I thought stackoverflow! So, can anyone please, please help me out here?

*ps : If you need any further clarification about database (or anything else) please feel free to ask..

pps : I am using ms-access 2007 and no I can't migrate to sql server due to some reason unimportant at this discussion*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yeah!!!
I have solved it myself actually!
Here's the solution..

```
SELECT Classes.ClassId, Classes.ClassName, Subjects.SubjectId, Subjects.SubjectName, Teachers.TeacherId, Teachers.TeacherName
FROM (Teachers INNER JOIN (Classes INNER JOIN TeacherClass ON Classes.ClassId = TeacherClass.ClassId) ON Teachers.TeacherId = TeacherClass.TeacherId) INNER JOIN (Subjects INNER JOIN TeacherSubject ON Subjects.SubjectId = TeacherSubject.SubjectId) ON Teachers.TeacherId = TeacherSubject.TeacherId
where classes.classid = k and subjects.subjectid = p
GROUP BY Classes.ClassId, Subjects.SubjectId, Teachers.TeacherId, classes.classname, subjects.subjectname, teachers.teachername;
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use JOIN:

```
SELECT tc.TeacherId
FROM ClassSubject
INNER JOIN TeacherSubject ON TeacherSubject.SubjectId = ClassSubject.SubjectId
INNER JOIN TeacherClass ON TeacherClass.TeacerId = TeacherSubject.teacherId AND ON TeacherClass.ClassId = ClassSubject.ClassId
WHERE ClassSubject.ClassId = [Your ClassId]
AND ClassSubject.SubjectId = [Your SubjectId]
```

Comment: Seriously? Did you even read the whole question? The second way I showed here in which I tried is join, and if had really worked with access, you'd know that it doesn't even supports this syntax. You didn't need to ALL CAPS join, I know what a join is..
But thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select TeacherSubject.TeacherId From TeacherSubject 
INNER JOIN ClassSubject ON TeacherSubject.SubjectID=ClassSubject.SubjectID
INNER JOIN TeacherClass ON Teacherclass.ClassID=TeacherSubject.ClassID
Where TeacherClass.ClassID=1 AND ClassSubject.SubjectID=1
```

Ofcourse it MSS SQL syntax. I think for MS ACCESS you have have to use JOIN. To get the teacher name from the teacher class again you need to join this teacher ID with the Teacher class.